# JEditorPane not loading complete web page

Tags: java

So I am trying to make a website load in a JFrame, but it is not loading properly.

Here is my attempt and the code I am using:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setPage(new URL("https://explv.github.io"));

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(editorPane));
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The JEditorPane only supports HTML 3.2 (I think it is), so it is not very useful for loading web pages. You can only load simple HTML that you create that doesn't use any new features of HTML.